# Typescript use method signature from generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to do something like this? It would help quite a lot. Us the method signature from generics

```
class Foo<Parent extends Foo> {
    public bar<U extends Parameters<Parent.bar>>(x: U) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add an example of how you would use this? What's the point to type base method params using parent signature?

Answer (score 1):

You can't if you want `Parent` to extend `Foo`, since that would cause a circular dependency in the type, but you can do it if you constrain `Parent` to something else with a `bar`:

```
class Foo<Parent extends { bar: (...a: any[]) => any}> {
    public bar<U extends  Parameters<Parent['bar']>>(x: U) {
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AFMAnApgOwC7UwA9ccATGAb2gCMMAuaACgDpWwGxsBPAbQF0AlNAC8APmicuAX3EUAsAChoy6AAcArtRABLYDQxIAqgWJkY0NOjABbTCXQRUGHLh4ByWujd9RoxoQZDIXklFSlFcIVFEDtoeBFoEJV9dEZsdAZsdWtqTHRg6EipAG5FbEwAdzhEJFwuVUx4ADM4vwFmT0YeAAZBRUUgA)

You might also be interested in this version that spreads the arguments back to the `bar` function:

```
class Foo<Parent extends { bar: (...a: any[]) => any}> {
    public bar(...x: Parameters<Parent['bar']>) {
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AFMAnApgOwC7UwA9ccATGAb2gCMMAuaACgDpWwGxsBPAbQF0AlNAC8APmicuAX3EUAsAChoy6AAcArtRABLYDQwtWhBmnRgAtphLoIqDDlw8A5LXRO+oofKUqpivwqKIFbQ8CLQ3ir66IzY6AzY6ubUmOhe0AFSANyK2JgA7nCISLhcqpjwAGahoowCzK6MAAwCiopAA)